# Is there a Stata function to delete the date in a DateTime variable?

Tags: datetime, stata

I have a date-time variable called `assign1_submission` (type `double` and `format %tchh:MM:SS_AM`). I have another date-time variable `time_due` (type `double` and `format %tchh:MM:SS_AM`).

```
gen double time_due = clock("12:00 PM", "hm")
format time_due %tchh:MM:SS_AM
```

In the `assign1_submission` that I imported from MS Excel, the variable only contained a time. However, in the data browser, Stata attached a date to the entry.

[image: Screenshot of Data Browser view when looking at the variable assign1_submission]

Despite only telling Stata a time, my `time_due` variable has a date in the entry.

[image: Screenshot of Data Browser view when looking at variable time_due]

What I want to do is delete the date in both variables, because I want to see the time difference between `time_due` and `assign1_submission`.
So, I tried the following code:

```
replace assign1_submission = hh(assign1_submission)
replace time_due = hh(time_due)

gen time_difference = time_due - assign1_submission
```

According to Stata:

> hh(e_tc)
> Description:  the hour corresponding to datetime e_tc (ms. since
> 01jan1960 00:00:00.000)

When running this code:

```
replace assign1_submission = hh(assign1_submission)
```

Stata disregards the previous time: everything is overwritten to state: 12:00 AM, where a date is still attached to the entry.
[image: Screenshot of Data Browser view when looking at variable hh(assign1_submission)]

Can someone please help to delete the date in both the `assign1_submission` and `time_due` variables so that I can determine the difference in hours between the two variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date-times in Stata are counted in milliseconds (ms) since the start of 1960. You can discard the date element by getting the remainder on division by 24 * 60 * 60000, the number of ms in 1 day.

The time concerned is still tacitly a time on 1 January 1960.

```
clear 
set obs 1 
gen double datetime = clock("4 July 2020 18:00:00", "DMY hms")
format datetime %tc 
gen double time = mod(datetime, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
format time %tcHH:MM:SS
l, noobs 

  +-------------------------------+
  |           datetime       time |
  |-------------------------------|
  | 04jul2020 18:00:00   18:00:00 |
  +-------------------------------+
```

Otherwise it's hard to follow your assertions. Stata doesn't change data because you look in the browser. What you are showing as daily dates pertains to different variables.